# final static value didn't update after JBoss AS war re-deployed

Tags: java, jboss, static, jvm, war

Here is what I did:

1. Compiled the file that contains the changed final static value.
2. Updated the corresponded .class file in the sever with the file that compiled in step 1
3. Changed "xxx.war.deployed" to "xxx.war.dodeploy" to re-deploy the war.

After this, I guess the final static value should be updated, but it didn't.

Only that I deleted the entire war file, upload and deploy it again. The value updated finally.

So, what caused this? Do final static values have the same life time as JVM?

Answer (score 2):

Static final variables of primitive or String type are actually *compile-time constants* and, as such, get inlined literally wherever they are used. Thereby you lose a reference to the originating class and no updates occur when that class changes. You need a full recompile instead.

There are ways to get around this, but none are particularly pleasant. You can use static *methods* to return the constant value, for example.

Answer (score 1):

It is caused due to the fact that static variables get Loaded when class is loaded by the ClassLoader and they are unloaded when the class can be unloaded and that can happen when the Classloader used is garbage collected.